# Is there an alternative to the skype service?

Tags: 13.04, skype, voip

On ubuntu 13.04 Skype segfaults constantly (I've read a couple of threads about fixing the issue and it is kind of works now expect it segfaults every time chat message comes in) so I'm thinking it is time to find it a replacement.

Which one should I choose?

Ok, I've seen previous post, yet only one answer in it highlights some alternatives. Also I want no the alternative skype client, but the whole ecosystem.

The one alternative presented ooVoo does not support linux and other goober shows unresolved dependency: libglew1.5

Comment: Anyone voting to reopen this care to explain *why* it isn't a dup?

Comment: @psusi I'm not voting anything but the original question was about alternative skype client while mine question is about alternative VoIP piece of software.

Comment: I'd say that software that does the same thing, even though it isn't compatible with skype per se, is a perfectly good answer to the original question, so there's no need for another question.

Comment: @psusi  What is "the same thing" we are talking here? It is ability to connect to his skype contacts, because there are may be a variety of reasons person stuck with skype (for example a large base of contacts not willing to move to alternative). So no, similar service would not be an answer for that question while it would be a desired answer for mine, you see?

Comment: I do see, and I'm saying they are close enough that it would be a good answer ( though probably not the best ) for that question.

Comment: @psusi they are not closer than percentage of his skype contacts willing to install alternative (and guess how much it is).

Answer (score 6, accepted):

A Free Skype Alternative [**Jitsi**](https://jitsi.org/Main/HomePage) , 
For video tutorial check **[Jupiterbroadcasting](http://www.jupiterbroadcasting.com/34976/a-free-skype-alternative-las-s26e05/)**

[image]